# I'm trying to add a fixed value in the method copy

Tags: postgresql, copy

I'm trying to add a fixed value in the method copy.
There is a csv file, but in addition to the data from it, I want to add a fixed value to the table.
In vertica there is column‑as‑expression.

```
create table if not exists public.test
    (
    ID int,
    OPTION_TYPE varchar(500),
    dttm date, 
    NUM_CSV int
    )
```

Copy:

```
 COPY public.test(
            ID,OPTION_TYPE,DTTM,
            NUM_CSV AS 1
            )
            FROM STDIN
            WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

I tried to do it via query, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly inventing new syntax is rarely the path to success.
The only way I can think of is changing the default value:

```
ALTER TABLE public.test ALTER num_csv SET DEFAULT 1;
```

Then omit that column in the `COPY` statement:

```
COPY public.test (id, option_type, dttm) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT 'csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by by providing the fixed value directly in the COPY command.
The query is as follows:

```
COPY public.test (ID, OPTION_TYPE, DTTM, NUM_CSV)
FROM '/path/to/your/csv/file.csv' 
WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',');

UPDATE public.test SET NUM_CSV = 1;
```

Use the COPY command to load data from the CSV file into the table. Then, you run an UPDATE statement to set the value of NUM_CSV to 1 for all rows in the table.